# how to convert json data to specific alias and with comma seperated values in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have one table of product_attributes that is below:-

```
id          attr_details
1          {"Manufacturer":"Lennovo","Warranty":"6 months"}
2          {"Manufacturer":"HP","Warranty":"6 months"}
3          {"Manufacturer":"DEll","Warranty":"12 months","Type":"DDR"}
4          {"Size":"36","Color":"Red","Material":"Fabric"}
```

My attr_details column data stored in json. My expected Output is like below:-

```
label           values
Manufacturer     Lennovo,HP,DEll
Warranty         6 months,12 months
Type             DDR
 Size            36
 Color           Red
 Material        Fabric
```

The attr_details json is not predefined it can be any userdefined input json. So can anyone help me how to achieve this output.

Comment: _"The attr_details json is not predefined it can be any dynamic json"_ include this scenario into your question. Give us an illustration on what you mean by that.

Comment: means that json is not fixed for each record that can be any i am updating the question see  again

Comment: @FaNo_FN you understand the question now?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The way I see it, it may have to use a prepared statement. I'm not entirely sure if MySQL have anything built-in for this kind of operation but the possible way to get the attribute title is using [JSON_KEYS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys) then use that result to generate a dynamic query.

Comment: Can you run `SELECT @@version` and tell us the exact version here?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/17ewx76

Comment: @FaNo_FN any help?

Comment: I'm looking for options but there's not a lot of it. I can see a possibility but it'll take time to construct the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT '",colname,":' AS 'Label', GROUP_CONCAT(val) 
            FROM (SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.", colname,"')) AS 'val'  
                FROM mytable /*you can add the WHERE condition in here*/ GROUP BY val) A 
                      GROUP BY Label") SEPARATOR " UNION ")
       INTO @sql
FROM
(WITH RECURSIVE data AS (
  SELECT attr_details,JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(attr_details), '$[0]') AS colname, 0 AS idx FROM mytable
  UNION
  SELECT attr_details,JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(attr_details), CONCAT('$[', d.idx + 1, ']')) 
  AS colname, d.idx + 1 AS idx FROM data AS d
  WHERE d.idx < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_KEYS(attr_details)) - 1
) SELECT colname
FROM data
GROUP BY colname) V;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This is the closest I can get. The `WITH RECURSIVE ..` part I use to list out all the keys as single row value each. That one I was referring to a query from the [comment section in the MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_keys/). Then I construct the query using combination of `CONCAT` + `GROUP_CONCAT`. Lastly, I used prepared statement to execute the query. Here is the final output of `@sql`:

```
SELECT 'Color:' AS 'Label', GROUP_CONCAT(val) 
            FROM (
            SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.Color')) AS 'val'  
            FROM mytable GROUP BY val) A 
            GROUP BY Label UNION 
SELECT 'Manufacturer:' AS 'Label', GROUP_CONCAT(val) 
            FROM (
            SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.Manufacturer')) AS 'val'  
            FROM mytable GROUP BY val) A 
            GROUP BY Label UNION 
SELECT 'Material:' AS 'Label', GROUP_CONCAT(val) 
            FROM (
            SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.Material')) AS 'val'  
            FROM mytable GROUP BY val) A 
            GROUP BY Label UNION 
SELECT 'Size:' AS 'Label', GROUP_CONCAT(val) 
            FROM (
            SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.Size')) AS 'val'  
            FROM mytable GROUP BY val) A 
            GROUP BY Label UNION 
SELECT 'Type:' AS 'Label', GROUP_CONCAT(val) 
            FROM (
            SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.Type')) AS 'val'  
            FROM mytable GROUP BY val) A 
            GROUP BY Label UNION 
SELECT 'Warranty:' AS 'Label', GROUP_CONCAT(val) 
            FROM (
            SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(attr_details,'$.Warranty')) AS 'val'  
            FROM mytable GROUP BY val) A 
            GROUP BY Label
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=297077bd4b40f35d041af72b93224ec5)

Comment: DEALLOCATE stmt
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'stmt' at line 1

Comment: it works if i removed the DEALLOCATE stmt  from query ... not sure is it required or not?

Comment: if you see the your ouptut 6 months, 6 months is repeating. can we make unique? each label value?

Comment: That's strange.. the fiddle is also Mariadb 10.4 but it doesn't return an error. I have a local Mariadb 10.3 running the query with no error as well. It's possible to return `6 months` value only once but I have to inspect the query again. Currently I'm on mobile so can't test further. I'll get back to you when I'm able to test.

Comment: I've updated the query @kunal . Please try it

Comment: i have one question for you if i want to add one where conditions like myTable.id = 1 at what part i can add?

Comment: If you want to add condition it will be in between the second syntax `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( ...... INTO @sql`. That part is assigning `@sql` variable with the final generated query so if you wanted to add a `WHERE ..` it should be in between third line of `... FROM mytable GROUP BY val ..` . I've edited my answer and put a comment where you should add the condition.

Comment: By the way @kunal, I figured out the correct deallocate statement should be `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`. Previously I did `DEALLOCATE stmt;` only which is why it returned error.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT jsontable.label
    FROM test
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( JSON_KEYS(test.attr_details),
                           '$[*]' COLUMNS ( label VARCHAR(255) PATH '$' )) jsontable
)
SELECT cte.label, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT JSON_EXTRACT(test.attr_details, CONCAT('$.', cte.label))) `values`
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN test
GROUP BY label;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab92deb1dc20eef0f090f841ce2c6cd0

Comment: i already mentioned that my json is not fixed it can be any that means Manufacturer,Warranty,Type these are not fixed

Comment: @kunal Test another variant.

Comment: the label colmn is no in my database

Comment: can you create sql fiddle of your output

Comment: SELECT product_attributes.label, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT JSON_EXTRACT(product_attributes.attr_details, CONCAT('$.', product_attributes.label))) `values`
FROM product_attributes
CROSS JOIN product_attributes
GROUP BY label;

Comment: @kunal ??? You don't see the fiddle link? if so I cannot help you...

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'product_attributes'

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( JSON_KEYS(product_attributes.attr_details),
                           '$[...' at line 4

Comment: @kunal You cannot detect what is your DBMS correctly? This is your problem. MySQL <> MariaDB. Similar, true, but not equal.

Comment: @kunal Screenshots is not needed. I know that JSON_TABLE is implemented in MariaDB 10.6 only. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234312/discussion-between-kunal-and-akina).

Comment: so what we can do now?