# How can I show all array from 0 to 4 individually

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, xampp

I really need your help To solve this array problem. Basically want to show each array values on wp data table. Its store on xampp wp_option table.

How can i use query to show them on data table.

Example of my databse: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Vna_-ux7T4mNEGPZAq1lrA.png
[Its shows the table column and rows]
Here are the example of my option_value json files .

```
{"id":1,"number":false,"input":"My table is now working","textarea":"Go to hell , you will find there","select":false,"radio":false,"hidden":false,"myFile":"C:\\\\fakepath\\\\FI.txt","fineuploader":false,"date":false,"checkbox":false,"button":false,"reset":false}
```

Its a json_encoded data. Now by global wpdb I want to show them in wordpress data table.
I just need the **query** through which i can loop all the keys and values and show them on data table.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert json data to specific alias and with comma seperated values in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172861/how-to-convert-json-data-to-specific-alias-and-with-comma-seperated-values-in-my)

Comment: Actually Its already stored on database now i want to show them on wordpress datatable fields. To do that, i need an sql query.

Comment: Have you referred to the linked question? I have a feeling that you have a similar situation and yes there are suggested MySQL queries solution in there.